# Barcode Scanning library for Blackberry other than Zxing

Tags: blackberry, barcode-scanner

I am searching for a library whether is paid or open source for barcode scanning for Blackberry.
I have found one. i.e. zxing. Please suggest some other libraries if you are aware of that.

I want a library which can read/scan Barcode type Code 25.
Please help me with that.

Thanks

Comment: refer http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/barcodelib/BarcodeScanner.html

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/readbarj/

Comment: I want library like zxing. whether it is paid or open source.

Comment: Note that zxing is included in the OS as of 6.0.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But I want similar library for barcode scanning. Actually I am creating barcode scanner for BB OS 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point that Code 25 (AKA 2 of 5, and its interleaved variant) is decoded by Android's Barcode Scanner, which in turn uses ZXing. (Despite officially, ZXing project page does not list it as supported).

You could download the latest version of ZXing and repackage the core for BB with different package names so that they do not collide with the built in ZXing libraries (which are an older version), and test it.

Comment: Oh thanks...I will definitely try that.May be that helps but what if I dont want to go with zxing library and use other libraries?? which are the available for BB

Answer (score 0):

```
Import the required classes.
import java.util.*;

import net.rim.device.api.barcodelib.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;

import com.google.zxing.*;
Create a class to run the application by extending UiApplication.
public final class BarcodeScanDemo extends UiApplication
{ 
Create a constructor for the class, and display a BarcodeScanDemoScreen object.
    public BarcodeScanDemo()
{
    pushScreen(new BarcodeScanDemoScreen());
}
Create the main method that starts the application.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new BarcodeScanDemo().enterEventDispatcher();
    }
}
Define a screen for your class that extends the MainScreen class.
final class BarcodeScanDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{
Create a constructor for the screen.
    public BarcodeScanDemoScreen() 
    { 
Create a BarcodeDecoderListener object to handle the data that is received when a barcode is scanned. In it, implement barcodeDecoded() to process the raw data that is sent by the decoder.
        BarcodeDecoderListener listener = new BarcodeDecoderListener()
        {
            public void barcodeDecoded( String rawText )
            {
                // Do something with the raw text
            }
        };
Create a Hashtable to store decoding hints in.
        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
Create a new Vector object to store barcode formats in.
        Vector formats = new Vector();
Add the BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE constant to the Vector object using Vector.addElement(Object obj). You can add more than one constant (hint) to a Vector object.
        formats.addElement(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
Invoke Hashtable.put(Object key, Object value), and add the Vector object to the hash table. The DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS constant is used to specify that the hints contained in the Vector object are barcode formats. Other constants for decoding hints can be found in the com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType class.
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);
Construct a BarcodeDecoder object to decode data received from the camera's viewfinder into usable raw data. Pass the Hashtable object into it.
        BarcodeDecoder decoder = new BarcodeDecoder( hints ); 
Create a try block, and construct a MainScreen object to contain the camera viewfinder.
        try
        {
            MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
Construct a BarcodeScanner object, and pass the BarcodeDecoder and BarcodeListener objects into it. Invoke BarcodeScanner.getVideoControl() to return a VideoControl object. Invoke VideoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true) to set the video's display to full screen.
            BarcodeScanner scanner = new BarcodeScanner( decoder,
                                         listener );
            scanner.getVideoControl().setDisplayFullScreen( true );
Invoke Screen.add(Field field) to add the barcode scanner's view finder to the screen, then invoke UiApplication.pushScreen(Screen screen) to display the viewfinder.
            screen.add( scanner.getViewFinder() );
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( screen );
Start the barcode scanner by invoking BarcodeScanner.startScan(). Close the try block.
            scanner.startScan();
        }
Open a catch block to catch any errors that may occur.
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Catch errors here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is from- http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Create_a_barcode_scanner_1585041_11.jsp

Comment: Thanks for the code. This will work only for BB OS >6.0. I want library like zxing.